# Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsbundle

during the progress of my app I decided to change from using a UIStoryboard to .xib file, and now I get the error:

*Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle*

How can I fix this problem within the Simulator part of my app?

Comment: Did you edit the `Info.plist` to remove the *Main Storyboard base file*?

Answer (score 45):

Remove the `"Main storyboard file base name"` or `"UIMainStoryboardFile"` Key from your info.plist file.

[image: info.plist]

Comment: I encounter this problem recently, and I don't know why because it run without problem previously. Could you please explain us what happen here?

Comment: It will leave app with a black screen :/

Comment: now my app is just a black screen as well, don't do this.

Comment: Yup, this breaks the app. :'D Solution below works for me though.

Answer (score 15):

if you are using SceneDelegate in iOS13, Try to remove this key.

[image: Main storyboard in UIScene]

Comment: Thank you a million times. This was driving me wild.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 9):

Click Your Story board

then do step 2 and step 3

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Add these line to your action method**

Where "Main" will be same as it as

let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

let secondVc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ControllerName") as! ControllerName

present(secondVc, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: Since the question was about Objective-c swift code may not really help.